# Is there a way to set a delay for VisualState transition?

Tags: silverlight, animation, visualstatemanager

I'd like for my control to start visual state transition animation after some delay.
I tried setting BeginTime on a visual state Storyboard. But it gave nothing :(
Is there any way to do this?

```
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=controlRoot}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOverData"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>

     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlockChart}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOverCharts"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlockChart}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=grid}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOverCharts"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=grid}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>

     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlockData}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOverData"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=textBlockData}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=grid1}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="MouseOverData"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=grid1}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Normal"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" />
            <VisualTransition From="MouseOverCharts" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="Normal">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverCharts">
            <Storyboard>
              <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFEFE78A" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockChart" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockChart" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockChart" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FFEFE78A" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockChartContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="220" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOverData">
            <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:10">
              <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0" To="#FFEFE78A" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockDataContent" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
              <ColorAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0" To="#FFEFE78A" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockData" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
              <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0" To="10" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockData" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
              <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlockData" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
              <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0" To="220" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're on the right track.  Can you post your xaml for the storyboard definition.  using a storyboard is the correct approach.

Comment: Posted the code. You can see MouseOverData visual state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"` inside `<VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" />`

Comment: Not very obvious, but it helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeginTime property on the Storyboard.

Example:

```
<Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:2">

</Storyboard>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)